# AutoMapper: implementing MaxDepth in custom ITypeConverter

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having some trouble with a custom ITypeConverter in AutoMapper, regarding circular references. Take the following example: Let's say a `House` can have a `List<Person>` in it, and each of those `Persons` belong to a `House`. We could model that like so:

```
public class House 
{
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}
```

And maybe we have some DTOs that look like this:

```
public class HouseDto
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDto> People { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDto
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
    public HouseDto House { get;set; }
}
```

Because AutoMapper's convention-based mapping is quite slow, I've chosen to use custom type converters in order to avoid all of the reflection AutoMapper uses. So I have two converters something like this:

```
public class HouseConverter : ITypeConverter<House, HouseDto>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public HouseConverter(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public HouseDto Convert(House source, HouseDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;

        destination = destination ?? new HouseDto();
        destination.PropertyB = source.PropertyB;
        destination.People = _mapper.Map<List<PersonDto>>(source.People);

        return destination;
    }
}

public class PersonConverter : ITypeConverter<Person, PersonDto>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public PersonConverter(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public PersoneDto Convert(Person source, PersonDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source == null) return null;

        destination = destination ?? new PersonDto();
        destination.PropertyB = source.PropertyB;
        destination.House = _mapper.Map<HouseDto>(source.House);

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Obviously this is going to cause a StackOverflowException, as the relationships create a circular reference. To avoid this AutoMapper has a MaxDepth option you can use when using the built-in mapping methods, but this functionality obviously gets lost when you start using your own converters. I'd like some guidance on the correct way to implement this in a custom converter.

**Here's the problem:** prior to v5.0 of AutoMapper, custom converters had access to a ResolutionContext that included the value for MaxDepth and it looks like it also included a current depth as well. This would have allowed me to detect hitting the depth limit and stop any further recursion. However, with the changes to ResolutionContext in 5.0 I can't find any way to access the MaxDepth or current depth. **Are those values still available to an ITypeConverter somehow, or are we expected to implement this ourselves now?** The online documentation doesn't offer a lot of detail on this specific usage.